# SQLPLus waits... why?

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

I am new to SQL Plus. I am trying to update a record using SQL Plus in a batch file. Can this be done?

When I try this, it just waits and waits and waits... I do not know why.

This is my test.sql file:

```
CONNECT scott/tiger@server
SPOOL ./ResetTable.status
SET LINESIZE 100
SET PAGESIZE 50
UPDATE MY_DBO.ControlTable SET TriggerFlag = 1;
COMMIT;
SPOOL OFF
EXIT;
```

This is my test.bat file

```
sqlplus /nolog @"C:\test.sql"
exit
```

However, this works...

This is my test.sql file:

```
CONNECT scott/tiger@server
SPOOL ./ResetTable.status
SET LINESIZE 100
SET PAGESIZE 50
select * from  MY_DBO.ControlTable ;
SPOOL OFF
EXIT;
```

This is my test.bat file

```
sqlplus /nolog @"C:\test.sql"
exit
```

Answer (score 3):

I would wager that some other session has locked one or more of the rows in `MY_DBO.ControlTable` where the `TriggerFlag` is 1.

From a different session, can you query `DBA_BLOCKERS` and `DBA_WAITERS`?  If you're seeing rows in those tables, can you post the results?

Comment: You got in before Tony Andrews this time!

Comment: @APC - Had to happen eventually!